# Div content overlaps on multi-part form

Tags: html, css

When advancing through a multi-part form, the div content from below the form overlaps when you click the Previous button. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious.

[Here is the form](http://ec2-52-0-24-204.compute-1.amazonaws.com/docgen/app/)

[And an image of the overlap problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7whD.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlflow. Rather than linking to your code, please add a minimal example of code that reproduces the problem here. For more information on how to ask good questions, consult the help centre at https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `min-height` for form.

```
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px bottom;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
    min-height: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it look like your JQuery issue when click on previous button position: absolute; remain their you need to remove that or you can add height their on #msform

Comment: Indeed. You have to remove position:absolute, after clicking on previous button.

Answer (score 0):

replace `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` in `fieldset` that might coming from javscript/JQuery or give it `min-height` will solve your issue